# What's the maximum MTU for Wi-Fi 6 (802.11 ax)?

Tags: wireless-networking, mtu

The only thing I found about "Wi-Fi 6 MTU" are [old posts](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/37324/59085) about the old standards. Wi-Fi 6 is new and has higher speeds where higher MTUs are more suitable than in slower networks.

Does Wi-Fi 6 support more than 2304 bytes?